# How to add IEEEtran.cls to be read automatically?

Tags: packages, mactex

I am using a MacOS and I want to copy the `IEEEtran.cls` file into the latex directory such that it is read automatically.

I have a file in the directory `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist/tex/latex/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls`

But when I do `\documentclass{IEEEtran}` it fails to read the file.

Please help if anyone has seen this.

Comment: Have you run `texhash`? Is `/opt/local/share/texmf-texlive-dist` included in the directory list of `kpsewhich --expand-braces '$TEXMF'`?

Comment: Which TeX system do you use? If you have MacTeX, it should already be available, but that would be inside `\usr\local\texlive`.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is that the directory you have put the class file is not in the input path search list. This can be defined using the `TEXINPUTS` environmental variable e.g.

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:/somepath/lib/latex:
```

would be used to have it search in `/somepath/lib/latex` as well as current directory. I have such a directory for odd bits of nonstandard LaTeX configuration and class files.

Comment: This clobbers the path. Ensure you do: `export TEXINPUTS=$TEXINPUTS:.:/path/
`